# Python indentation is off? Fail to see how

Tags: python, indentation

I'm trying to run my code to see if everything checks out, but for some reason it keeps saying that the indentation is wrong. I'm failing to see how. I used all tabs, and not a mix of tabs and spaces as far as i know, and most are just lined up by hitting enter after the semi-colon of the function definition.

```
# This function needs to be defined: parameter, body definition
    def HalfAdder(self,x,y):
                S = int((x and not y) or (not x and y))
                C = int((x and y))
                return (S, C)
                pass

    def FullAdder(self,x,y,z):
                xy = int((x and not y) or (not x and y))
                S = int((z and not xy) or (not z and xy))
                xyz = int((z and xy))
                C1 = int((x and y) or (xyz))
                return (S,C1)
                pass
```

Comment: Make the defs start at the beginning of the line.

Comment: also its a colon, not semi colon :)

Comment: The indentation is specified in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Comment: Why on earth do you have a `pass` (or anything, for that matter) *after* a `return`? And what makes you certain you only have tabs (note that the style guide recommends spaces)?

Comment: hes actually missing spaces and tabs...

Comment: If this is part of a class, post the entire module. However, that will most likely be too long. Have you considered systematically commenting and uncommenting regions of your code to find out where the SyntaxError is, if you can't decipher it from the Error message itself?

Comment: Run your code with ```python -tt yourfile.py``` to make sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces..

Comment: If on a unix machine. open the file `vi file.py` then press shift + ; and type `%retab!` .

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is specified in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and you got your indentation levels wrong.

The fixed indentation looks like this:

```
# This function needs to be defined: parameter, body definition

def HalfAdder(self, x, y):
    S = int((x and not y) or (not x and y))
    C = int((x and y))
    return (S, C)

def FullAdder(self, x, y, z):
    xy = int((x and not y) or (not x and y))
    S = int((z and not xy) or (not z and xy))
    xyz = int((z and xy))
    C1 = int((x and y) or (xyz))
    return (S, C1)
```

Since the function definitions were not on the first level and the inner part of the functions were on the third level, not on the second as they should.

Comment: Indentation is *recommended* in PEP8, and as long as you're consistent using tabs or different numbers of spaces works just fine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No. PEP8 is the law, and we are its deputies. We must crack the whip of the law over the beginners lest they profane the sacred standards and create abominations like the one in the OP.